# Zip large amount files by splitting into multiple zip and download with JSZip

Tags: javascript, large-files, jszip

I need to make a function zip multiple files (around 1000 files > 6GB) but seem like browser can't handle that task in 1 zip. So can I split into multiple zip file and zip asynchronously? Also does this way have better performance ? I'm using JSZip library. Thanks.

Comment: That would seem like a large task for any application, and not a very suited one for a frontend (assuming that this is a frontend). You might be better of handling this server side. Have you tried to do your proposed method? In theory performance should be worse as you're doing the same work multiple times. Try it out and you'll know for sure.

Comment: Thanks. Yes it's React App. But I think on server side also not have enough memory to process all the files.

Comment: If memory is the issue, then it's a hardware limitation, which is hard to code around.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.